# How to use SUMIFS if there is a gap between cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have spreadsheet as in the picture attached:
[image]

Is there any other way to sum it without using two SUMIFS due to gap between cells?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried just referencing the entire column, completely ignoring the fact that there's a break in the middle? If the value in `A:A` doesn't match the value in `F5`, it'll be ignored. SUMIFS should have no trouble with this.

Comment: SUMIFS will ignore the gap:  `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,F5,B:B,">0")` at least in Excel it will

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest two possible Formula:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- an array (CSE) Formula in cell O40 (gets unique list):

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($L$40:$L$54,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($O$39:O39,$L$40:$L$54),0)),"")}
  ```

*Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.*

- Formula in cell P40:

  ```
  =IF(P$39="Posetive",SUMPRODUCT(($L$40:$L$54=$O40)*($M$40:$M$54>0)*($M$40:$M$54)),SUMPRODUCT(($L$40:$L$54=$O40)*($M$40:$M$54<0)*($M$40:$M$54)))
  ```

*Fill formula across range.*

- Formula in cell S40:

  ```
  =IF(S$39="Posetive",SUMIFS($M$40:$M$54,$L$40:$L$54,"<>",$L$40:$L$54,$O40,$M$40:$M$54,">0"),SUMIFS($M$40:$M$54,$L$40:$L$54,"<>",$L$40:$L$54,$O40,$M$40:$M$54,"<0"))
  ```

*Fill formula across range.*

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*